# permissive equality test on string

Tags: python, path

I'm a python newbie with a problem too hard to tackle.

I have a string defining a path, were all the spaces have been converted to underscores.
How can I find if it corresponds to a real path?

e.g. a string like `/some/path_to/directory_1/and_to/directory_2`
with a real path: `/some/path_to/directory 1/and_to/directory 2`

notice that the real path can contain BOTH spaces and underscores.

How can I feed it to `os.path.exists()` ???

thanks
  alessandro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) but replacing every underscore with a range `[ _]`:

```
import glob
glob.glob('/some/path_to/directory_1/and_to/directory_2'.replace('_', '[ _]'))
```

Note that this will fail if your path contains the character `[`. You can fix this by first replacing `[` with `[[]`.

Comment: ...by *first* replacing `[` with `[[]`.

Comment: like this?  p1='/some/path_to/directory_1/and_to/directory_2'.replace('_', '[ _]')   
p2='/some/path_to/directory_1/and_to/directory_2'.replace('[', '[[]')   glob.glob(p2)

Comment: +1: Those who forget about the glob module are doomed to attempt to recreate it badly for a few minutes before hitting refresh on the SO question to see an answer from someone who hasn't.

Comment: You'll also need to "escape" `?` and `*` in the same way.